# c# sharpcompress : How to check progress

Tags: c#, progress, rar, sharpcompress

```
IArchive rar = SharpCompress.Archive.Rar.RarArchive.Open(new FileInfo("ze.rar"), SharpCompress.Common.Options.None);
        rar.WriteToDirectory(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\DATA", SharpCompress.Common.ExtractOptions.Overwrite);
```

With the above code i'm able to extract the rar file, however i would like to show the progress through the console. How can i check the progress?

Comment: `IArchive.WriteToDirectory()` simply loops over all entries in the Archived and calls `WriteToDirectory()` on each. Implement this manually if you want to report progress (ie. how many entries you've extracted so far)

Comment: However, one entry might be bigger than other!!

Comment: like, much bigger ex: 12MB and 1GB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should provide a sample of how to calculate the current percentage of the extraction operation.  Thanks to @MathiasRJessen for pointing out the behavior of `IArchive.WriteToDirectory` extension.

```
IArchive rar = SharpCompress.Archive.Rar.RarArchive.Open(new FileInfo("ze.rar"), SharpCompress.Common.Options.None);
string directory = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "DATA");

// Calculate the total extraction size.
double totalSize = rar.Entries.Where(e => !e.IsDirectory).Sum(e => e.Size);
long completed = 0;

// Use the same logic for extracting each file like IArchive.WriteToDirectory extension.
foreach (var entry in rar.Entries.Where(e => !e.IsDirectory))
{
    entry.WriteToDirectory(directory, ExtractOptions.Overwrite);

    // Track each individual extraction.
    completed += entry.Size;
    var percentage = completed / totalSize;
    // TODO do something with percentage.
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really work if you're trying to get the percentage on one large unpacked file.

Comment: It looks like IArchiveEntry exposes a method `OpenEntryStream`. That could be used to to track individual entries progress as data is being copied from the stream to the target file.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I find that this code works better then the answer.

```
Well, this was not properly documented anywhere on the Internet. There were some possibilities, but they wouldn't calculate properly. This is a working Progress percentage calculation for decompressing archives in SharpCompress.
```

This is taken from my Decompression Class, so there is extra information in the logic. However, what is important is casting the 'CompressedBytesRead' to double, and dividing it into the total size of the archive which should also be cast to double.

`

```
public static double Percentage {get; set;}

public static long totalSize { get; set; }

public static void BeginDecompression(string fullFileName, string fileName)
{
    try
    {               

        var settings = new Configuration().GetSettings();

        CurrentExtractionName = (Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName)); 


        StringHelpers.ItemInfo item = StringHelpers.GetItemInfo(fileName);

        string extractPath = settings.EmbyAutoOrganizeFolderPath + "\\" +
                             (Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName));
        Directory.CreateDirectory(extractPath);
        IArchive archive = ArchiveFactory.Open(fullFileName);

        // Calculate the total extraction size.
        totalSize = archive.TotalSize;

        Console.WriteLine(totalSize);

        foreach (IArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries.Where(entry => !entry.IsDirectory))
        {
            archive.EntryExtractionEnd += FileMoveSuccess; 
            archive.CompressedBytesRead += Archive_CompressedBytesRead;
            entry.WriteToDirectory(extractPath, ExtractOptions.ExtractFullPath | ExtractOptions.Overwrite);

        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
    }
}

private static void Archive_CompressedBytesRead(object sender, CompressedBytesReadEventArgs e)
{            
    Percentage = ((double)e.CompressedBytesRead / (double)totalSize) * 100;

    Console.WriteLine(Percentage);
}
```

`

If anyone has something better, I'm all ears, but this will work to implement a progress bar.